# What is this message on the KuCoin API? code: '200000', msg: 'The interface is offline'

Tags: api, request, cryptocurrency, kucoin

I'm trying to perform a transfer operation from my **main** account to a **trade** account using the KuCoin API but I'm getting the result:

```
{ code: '200000', msg: 'The interface is offline' }
```

What does it mean?

The result has the status code for a successful API request (200000), as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.kucoin.com/#request), but the operation doesn't seem to have completed. The balance in the main account is still the same as before the request, and the message "The interface is offline" seems to indicate that something went wrong.

I've competed this very same operation in many occasions before, same account, same trading pairs, proximately the same balance, so the problem doesn't seem to be caused by some incorrect parameter being passed in the request.